# Ember data JSON Api adapter set all attributes to undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In an application using ember 2.1.0 and ember-data 2.1.0, I have this model :

```
# app/models/user.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr()
});
```

And this route :

```
# app/routes/subscriptions/new.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    this.store.findRecord('user', 1).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.id)
      console.log(data.get('email'))
    })
    return this.store.find('user', 1);
  }
});
```

I have this adapter :

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({host: 'http://localhost:5000'})
```

This data is returned by the server :

```
{"data":{"id":"1","type":"users","attributes":{"email":"test@test.com"}}}
```

In the console, I have the user id but the email is undefined. In the template, `{{model.email}}` gives nothing.

I may miss something but it's so simple. Is it my mistake or a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also specify `email` attribute in model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: xD Good luck with Ember.